# Error while trying to create workspace with catkin_make

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in ROS and i have a problem with workspace creation. I follow this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace. After catkin_make command i got errors:

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/vovanrew/anaconda2/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/vovanrew/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/vovanrew/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/vovanrew/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253683/error-while-trying-to-create-workspace-with-catkin_make/) by [vovanrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/29245/vovanrew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this bit:

```
execute_process(/home/vovanrew/anaconda2/bin/python
```

it would seem you have Anaconda installed and Catkin (and possibly the rest of ROS) is using that as the default interpreter.

But the `catkin_pkg` package has probably only been installed for the 'regular' Python interpreter (ie: the one that was installed by your Linux distribution).

There are numerous posts on ROS Answers about setting up Anaconda such that it can be used with ROS (although I mostly remember posts showing that it *doesn't* work). I suggest you search a bit and use one of the provided solutions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1